# JDK 1.6 GC AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

Please explain the detailed meaning of VALUE used in the GC option :

```
-XX:AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy
```

By default value given is 0.
Does this VALUE imply - the number of steps to use heuristics before real data is used?. What are implications of using a high(eg: 50 or 100)  or low value (eg: 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know to understand those arcane options is going directly to the source:
[psAdaptiveSizePolicy.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/2ecd0d1194d2/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psAdaptiveSizePolicy.cpp)

It seems that 1 and !=1 are the only valid choices.

`-XX:AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy=1` is used in coordination with `-XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyInitializingSteps=VALUE`.

Comment: Never went through the source code for vm options - thanks for the link!